# How to label rows with a specific value (including MS) if time occurs in given time interval in R

Tags: r, time, merge, data.table, posixct

I have two dataframes. DF1 has time intervals including milliseconds, with a corresponding value (behavior). DF2 has a column of times (including ms).

DF1:

```
                   START                   STOP behavior
1 2023-07-20 14:07:39.00 2023-07-20 12:07:39.14      dig
2 2023-07-20 14:07:39.27 2023-07-20 12:07:39.90      pig
```

DF2:

```
                             x                time label
133202 20/07/2023 12:07:39.020 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133203 20/07/2023 12:07:39.040 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133204 20/07/2023 12:07:39.060 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133205 20/07/2023 12:07:39.080 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133206 20/07/2023 12:07:39.100 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133207 20/07/2023 12:07:39.120 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133208 20/07/2023 12:07:39.140 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133209 20/07/2023 12:07:39.160 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133210 20/07/2023 12:07:39.180 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133211 20/07/2023 12:07:39.200 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133212 20/07/2023 12:07:39.220 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133213 20/07/2023 12:07:39.240 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133214 20/07/2023 12:07:39.260 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133215 20/07/2023 12:07:39.280 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133216 20/07/2023 12:07:39.300 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133217 20/07/2023 12:07:39.320 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133218 20/07/2023 12:07:39.340 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133219 20/07/2023 12:07:39.360 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133220 20/07/2023 12:07:39.380 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
133221 20/07/2023 12:07:39.400 2023-07-20 12:07:39    NA
```

I want to produce a dataframe that is DF2, but with a column that corresponds to behavior in DF1 if the time occurs within time intervals (including milliseconds) in DF1.

Desired output:

```
                            x                time label
133202 20/07/2023 12:07:39.020 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133203 20/07/2023 12:07:39.040 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133204 20/07/2023 12:07:39.060 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133205 20/07/2023 12:07:39.080 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133206 20/07/2023 12:07:39.100 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133207 20/07/2023 12:07:39.120 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133208 20/07/2023 12:07:39.140 2023-07-20 12:07:39   dig
133209 20/07/2023 12:07:39.160 2023-07-20 12:07:39  <NA>
133210 20/07/2023 12:07:39.180 2023-07-20 12:07:39  <NA>
133211 20/07/2023 12:07:39.200 2023-07-20 12:07:39  <NA>
133212 20/07/2023 12:07:39.220 2023-07-20 12:07:39  <NA>
133213 20/07/2023 12:07:39.240 2023-07-20 12:07:39  <NA>
133214 20/07/2023 12:07:39.260 2023-07-20 12:07:39  <NA>
133215 20/07/2023 12:07:39.280 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
133216 20/07/2023 12:07:39.300 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
133217 20/07/2023 12:07:39.320 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
133218 20/07/2023 12:07:39.340 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
133219 20/07/2023 12:07:39.360 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
133220 20/07/2023 12:07:39.380 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
133221 20/07/2023 12:07:39.400 2023-07-20 12:07:39   pig
```

Here are the data inputs:

DF1

> #new dataframe for testing#
>
> START<-c("2023-07-20 14:07:39.01", "2023-07-20 14:07:39.29")
>
> START<- as.POSIXct(START, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz = "UTC")
>
> START<-format(START, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
>
> STOP<-c("2023-07-20 14:07:39.14","2023-07-20 14:07:39.90")
>
> STOP<- as.POSIXct(STOP, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz = "UTC")
>
> STOP<-format(STOP, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2")
>
> behavior<-c("dig", "pig")
>
> DF1<-data.frame(START, STOP, behavior)
>
> DF1$START<- as.POSIXct(DF1$START, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz = "UTC")
>
> DF1$STOP<-as.POSIXct(DF1$STOP, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz = "UTC")
>
> DF1$START<-format(DF1$START, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2")
>
> DF1$STOP<-format(DF1$STOP, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2")

DF2 (x is time shown with ms, using `format(df2$x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2")`

```
structure(list(x = c("20/07/2023 12:07:39.020", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.040", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.060", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.080", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.100", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.120", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.140", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.160", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.180", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.200", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.220", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.240", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.260", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.280", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.300", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.320", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.340", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.360", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.380", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.400"
), time = structure(c(1689854859.02, 1689854859.04, 1689854859.06, 
1689854859.08, 1689854859.1, 1689854859.12, 1689854859.14, 1689854859.16, 
1689854859.18, 1689854859.2, 1689854859.22, 1689854859.24, 1689854859.26, 
1689854859.28, 1689854859.3, 1689854859.32, 1689854859.34, 1689854859.36, 
1689854859.38, 1689854859.4), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 133202:133221, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to produce this:

```
 dput(df2)
structure(list(x = c("20/07/2023 12:07:39.020", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.040", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.060", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.080", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.100", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.120", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.140", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.160", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.180", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.200", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.220", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.240", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.260", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.280", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.300", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.320", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.340", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.360", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.380", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.400"
), time = structure(c(1689854859.02, 1689854859.04, 1689854859.06, 
1689854859.08, 1689854859.1, 1689854859.12, 1689854859.14, 1689854859.16, 
1689854859.18, 1689854859.2, 1689854859.22, 1689854859.24, 1689854859.26, 
1689854859.28, 1689854859.3, 1689854859.32, 1689854859.34, 1689854859.36, 
1689854859.38, 1689854859.4), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    label = c("dig", "dig", "dig", "dig", "dig", "dig", "dig", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "pig", "pig", "pig", "pig", "pig", 
    "pig", "pig")), row.names = 133202:133221, class = "data.frame")
```

I can produce the desired result using the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  time_val <- df2$time[i]
  # Find the row where time_val falls within the interval
  interval_row <- which(time_val >= df1$START & time_val <= df1$STOP)
  
  # If there's a match, replace NA in label with the corresponding behavior
  if (length(interval_row) > 0) {
    behavior_val <- df1$behavior[interval_row]
    df2$label[i] <- behavior_val
  }
}
```

with the dummy data for DF1.

When I try to run using my full DF1 it doesn't seem to be finding the time intervals (throwing the error "Error in df2$label[i] <- behavior_val : replacement has length zero", even though the str() output is identical. I can't work out why. I have also noticed that this seems to only work when I use the columns of DF1 when they are `format(DF1$STOP, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2")` Not when they are formatted as POSIXct, which makes me think this is a very made way to do what I think is a simple problem!

I also think this is a messy solution and the for loop takes a while to run. Is there a better way to get my desired results and still accounting for the milliseconds in the time intervals and data?

I started to look into data.table solutions, but it doesn't sound like this is great to use for time intervals with milliseconds?

Please help!

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to merge behavior to `DF2` depending on whether `x` falls into the interval defined by `START` and `STOP`?

Below, I assume that the time in `DF1` is not 14h but 12h:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF1 <- as_tibble(DF1) |> 
  mutate(across(c(START, STOP), ymd_hms))

DF2 <- as_tibble(DF2) |> 
  mutate(x = dmy_hms(x))

DF2 |> 
  left_join(DF1, join_by(between(x, START, STOP))) |> 
  select(x, time, behavior)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 3
#>    x                   time                behavior
#>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>   
#>  1 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  2 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  3 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  4 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  5 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  6 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  7 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 dig     
#>  8 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 <NA>    
#>  9 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 <NA>    
#> 10 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 <NA>    
#> 11 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 <NA>    
#> 12 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 <NA>    
#> 13 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 <NA>    
#> 14 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig     
#> 15 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig     
#> 16 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig     
#> 17 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig     
#> 18 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig     
#> 19 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig     
#> 20 2023-07-20 12:07:39 2023-07-20 12:07:39 pig
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ah!!!! Thank you SOOOO much!! This is exactly what I was after, thank you!! Woops the 14h was a typo when posting this, its 12h originally :) Will ammend now. And sorry, why do you use the dmy_hms() rather than as,posix in this case? does it preserve the milliseconds better?

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this answer as the solution to your problem. I'm just used to the Tidyverse suit of packages, that's why I am using `dmy_hms()` in this case (included in the package lubridate). Should work equally well with base R functions!

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop you just missed to provide an `else df2$label[i] <- NA_character_`. Working with date and time can be tricky, you probably failed with the time zones, which should agree with each other.

```
df2[1:2] <- lapply(df2[1:2], as.POSIXct, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS', tz='GMT')
```

**You might use `data.table` since it's much faster.**

We `sapply` over the rows of *df1* and look if `df2$time` is `between` *START* and *STOP*. Note, that we use `data.table::between`; it throws a boolean matrix where we determine `max.col`, which we `replace` with `NA` if both are `FALSE`.

```
library(data.table)
> setDT(df2)[, label := df1$behavior[
+   max.col(r <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), \(i) 
+                       data.table::between(df2$x, 
+                                           df1[i, ]$START, 
+                                           df1[i, ]$STOP))) |>
+     replace(rowSums(r) == 0, NA)]]
> df2
                         x                   time label
 1: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.01 2023-07-20 12:07:39.01   dig
 2: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.03 2023-07-20 12:07:39.03   dig
 3: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.05 2023-07-20 12:07:39.05   dig
 4: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.07 2023-07-20 12:07:39.07   dig
 5: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.09 2023-07-20 12:07:39.09   dig
 6: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.11 2023-07-20 12:07:39.11   dig
 7: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.14 2023-07-20 12:07:39.14   dig
 8: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.16 2023-07-20 12:07:39.16  <NA>
 9: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.18 2023-07-20 12:07:39.18  <NA>
10: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.20 2023-07-20 12:07:39.20  <NA>
11: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.22 2023-07-20 12:07:39.22  <NA>
12: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.24 2023-07-20 12:07:39.24  <NA>
13: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.25 2023-07-20 12:07:39.25  <NA>
14: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.27 2023-07-20 12:07:39.27   pig
15: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.29 2023-07-20 12:07:39.29   pig
16: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.31 2023-07-20 12:07:39.31   pig
17: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.33 2023-07-20 12:07:39.33   pig
18: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.35 2023-07-20 12:07:39.35   pig
19: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.38 2023-07-20 12:07:39.38   pig
20: 2023-07-20 12:07:39.40 2023-07-20 12:07:39.40   pig
```

#### Benchmark

```
> f_for <- \(df2) {
+   for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
+     time_val <- df2$time[i]
+     interval_row <- which(time_val >= df1$START & time_val <= df1$STOP)
+     if (length(interval_row) > 0) {
+       df2$label[i] <- df1$behavior[interval_row]
+     } else {
+       df2$label[i] <- NA_character_
+     }
+   }
+   df2
+ }
> f_tidy <- \(df2) {
+   df2 |> 
+     dplyr::left_join(df1, dplyr::join_by(dplyr::between(x, START, STOP))) |> 
+     dplyr::select(x, time, behavior)
+ }
> f_dt <- \(dt) setDT(dt)[, label := df1$behavior[
+   max.col(r <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), \(i) 
+                       data.table::between(dt$x, 
+                                           df1[i, ]$START, 
+                                           df1[i, ]$STOP))) |>
+     replace(rowSums(r) == 0, NA)]]
> dt3 <- df3 <- df2[sample.int(nrow(df2), 5e3, replace=TRUE), ] |> as.data.frame()
> mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(`for`=f_for(df3), 
+                                      `tidy`=f_tidy(df3),
+                                      `data.table`=f_dt(dt3))
```

```
$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval cld
        for 651.363713 1178.234978 1197.410804 1200.984304 1224.139109 1324.71263   100  a 
       tidy   6.018196    6.531816   12.450828    6.837905    7.122139  557.42749   100   b
 data.table   1.664823    1.852909    2.199552    2.009043    2.112688   14.60731   100   b
```

```
> plot(mb, log='y')
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(START = structure(c(1689854859, 1689854859.27), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), STOP = structure(c(1689854859.14, 
1689854859.9), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    behavior = c("dig", "pig")), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df2)
structure(list(x = c("20/07/2023 12:07:39.020", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.040", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.060", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.080", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.100", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.120", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.140", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.160", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.180", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.200", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.220", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.240", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.260", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.280", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.300", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.320", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.340", 
"20/07/2023 12:07:39.360", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.380", "20/07/2023 12:07:39.400"
), time = structure(c(1689854859.02, 1689854859.04, 1689854859.06, 
1689854859.08, 1689854859.1, 1689854859.12, 1689854859.14, 1689854859.16, 
1689854859.18, 1689854859.2, 1689854859.22, 1689854859.24, 1689854859.26, 
1689854859.28, 1689854859.3, 1689854859.32, 1689854859.34, 1689854859.36, 
1689854859.38, 1689854859.4), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 133202:133221, class = "data.frame")
```